# GROUP BY name and ORDER BY point & time MYSQLi

Tags: mysqli

I'm new to this forum and I hope to find my solution about my problem.

I have this table :

```
name     time  points  car    date
Daniel | 55s | 210   | red   |20/01/2018
Daniel | 45s | 250   | green |21/01/2018
Julie  | 54s | 220   | red   |19/01/2018
Julie  | 33s | 150   | yellow|22/01/2018
```

and I wish to sort it like this

```
name     time  points  car    date
Daniel | 45s | 250    |green |21/01/2018
Julie  | 54s | 220    |red   |19/01/2018
```

**first sorting by points, than sorting by time and group by name (optional the count)**

I use this

```
    SELECT NAME, MAX(POINTS) POINTS, MAX(TIME) TIME, MAX(CAR) CAR, MAX(DATE) DATE
 FROM ( SELECT A.* FROM test A LEFT OUTER JOIN test B ON A.NAME=B.NAME AND
 A.POINTS<B.POINTS AND A.TIME>B.TIME WHERE B.NAME IS NULL ) as sub GROUP BY NAME
```

and I get this :

```
 name   POINTS  TIME    CAR     DATE    
Daniel  250     45    green     2018-01-21
Julie   220     54    yellow    2018-01-22
```

Julie should have car=red & 2018-01-19
For Daniel it looks good

how can I get thise values (car & date) ?

thanks
Nico

Comment: ... and if the answer comes from a "she".. is she welcome with her answer as well? If you did check SO for similar question and failed show that in your question as well. Self editing question is not a problem ;-)

Comment: hello ZF007, I don't me he, she...or aliens xD. I read during all the weekends many posts but haven't found the solution. If you can propose me one I will look after, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give this a shot.  It contains the table against itself and gets only records with the highest points and lowest time.

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(POINTS) POINTS, MAX(TIME) TIME
FROM
(
    SELECT A.* FROM test A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN test B ON A.NAME=B.NAME AND A.POINTS<B.POINTS AND A.TIME>B.TIME
    WHERE B.NAME IS NULL
) GROUP BY NAME
```

For additional, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT OUTERTEST.*,
    @row_num := IF(@prev_value=OUTERTEST.name,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber,
    @prev_value := OUTERTEST.name
FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY NAME, TEST.POINTS DESC, TEST.TIME ASC) OUTERTEST, (SELECT @row_num := 1, @prev_value := '') x
) A
WHERE A.ROWNUMBER=1
```

Comment: hello Ctznkane525 and thanks for your suggestion. Sadly it didn't work since LEFT OUTER JOIN wait a ON before WHERE. I couldn't make it work.

Comment: it doesn't always works, on a biggest table I posted later                              NAME POINTS  TIME  
Daniel  1140  55
Judie  1144  54

Comment: another change...try that please

Comment: Perfect it's great working. Do you know how to get additional information present in another column of selected line?

Comment: I edited and modified the post, added car & date, I wish to get the highest and lower time (OK so far) and want to know which car was used and at which date

Comment: since the car and date are just supplement columns, A.* has all the columns, so you can do MAX(car) and MAX(date) on the outer query...the nesting and the MAX is only because you might have the same NAME,POINTS,TIME combination and i didnt want to see 2 rows if that happened

Comment: I added a MAX(CAR) after the MAX(TIME) but get the wrong car for Julie, I guess I need to add something in the JOIN to get the right one but I didn't found it so far. Maybe I need another request to get the corresponding values but I need to find an common field first hu?

Comment: What did u run...what's it look like

Comment: If this doesn't work...youll have to create a SQL fiddle - SELECT SUB.NAME, MAX(SUB.POINTS) POINTS, MAX(SUB.TIME) TIME, C.CAR CAR, C.DATE DATE
 FROM ( SELECT A.* FROM test A LEFT OUTER JOIN test B ON A.NAME=B.NAME AND
 A.POINTS<B.POINTS AND A.TIME>B.TIME WHERE B.NAME IS NULL ) as sub LEFT OUTER JOIN test C on A.NAME=C.NAME AND C.TIME=A.TIME AND C.POINTS=A.POINTS GROUP BY SUB.NAME, C.CAR, C.DATE

Comment: the last JOIN didn't accept A. , I replaced it with sub. but that results has 2 times the same name

Comment: ill need to see a SQL fiddle...can you please create one

Comment: it seems sqlfiddle.com is down, do you have an alternative?

Comment: Sqlfiddle.com is up

Comment: ill check tonight (us eastern time...its 1030am now)

Comment: 2nd query is in there

Comment: OK I got it. I'm a bit confused because the table name is test and alias is TEST. Sadly it works with sqlfiddle but not in myphpadmin, the name are not grouped by hugggggg

Comment: Not sure what hugggg means...the way that one is written doesn't require a group by.  It takes the first record meeting a criteria....you can always make the aliases unique and see if phpmyadmin is ok...the query as you can see is valid

Comment: sorry, a bit nervous :), it seems all rows have ROWNUMBER=1 which is strange. I don't know why my server give another answer than sqlfiddle (I create the table with the same code!) https://gyazo.com/bc0a7b707ee0127961e159040c71c2b5

Comment: my server runs mysql 5.7 and sqlfiddle 5.6, is it th problem?

Comment: Try it in your code...maybe phpmyadmin is the problem?

Comment: I did it with a little PHP script and it's same result, I guess it's MySQL version 5.7, I try to build up a test station with 5.6 and see if I get correct RowNumber

Comment: I confirm you that the request doesn't work under Mysql 5.6 or 5.7, RowNumber is always = to 1. Why it work on sqlfiddle? no idea

Comment: I wish you could help me

Comment: I removed using TEST for both outer and inner...added variable with a default using a cross join...works in sqlfiddle

Comment: I added a COUNT(*) or MAX(Rownumber) to get the number of records I have in the database for every NAME. So far I get wrong results, can I do that in the same query or I will need to do another one to get the number of entries for each NAME?

Comment: you have to ask it as a separate question at this point...one question per thread...its an SO rule

Comment: I found it, added a COUNT with INNER JOIN :) not sure it's right but it works :P

Answer (score 0):

I did more test with this table

```
id  name    time    points
1   Daniel  55      1140
2   Judie   54      1144
3   Judie   33      1028
4   Daniel  45      1180
5   Judie   53      1148
```

I apply this request

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(POINTS) POINTS, sub.TIME FROM (SELECT * FROM Testpoint ORDER BY POINTS DESC, TIME ASC) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.name
```

I have the max point for each name but the time is not the right one

```
 name   POINTS  time    
Daniel  1180    55
Judie   1148    54
```

Judie should have 53 for time and not 54

What I did wrong?

thankyou
Nico